# How to set different localized string in different visual states in WP7 using Blend?

Tags: mvvm, localization, expression-blend, windows-phone

How do I set different localized strings in different visual states in WP7 using Blend without any code behind?

I can set different non-localized strings in different visual states (although it flickers).  That works, but how about localized strings?

If I change the string using data binding in Blend, Blend just overrides the data binding in Base state and not the actual state where I'm recording.

**EDIT:**

This is how I localize my strings:

I have a resources file named `AppPresources.resx`. Then I would do this in code:

```
    // setting localized button title
    mainButton.Content = AppResources.MainButtonText;
```

Then I have a `GlobalViewModelLocator` from MVVM Light Toolkit with the following Property for Databinding.

```
    private static AppResources _localizedStrings;
    public AppResources LocalizedStrings
    {
        get
        {
            if (_localizedStrings == null)
            {
                _localizedStrings = new AppResources();
            }
            return _localizedStrings;
        }
    }
```

And in xaml file:

```
<Button x:Name="mainButton" Content="{Binding LocalizedStrings.MainButtonText, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" ... />
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you're doing your localization

Comment: I've updated my question with how I would localize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do, is very close to what you're already doing. First, define a class named **Resources.cs** with following content

```
public class Resources
{
    private static AppResources resources = new AppResources();

    public AppResources LocalizedStrings
    {
        get
        {
            return resources;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows us to create a instance of your Resource File in XAML. To do this, open **App.xaml** and add following

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:Resources x:Key="Resources" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Now when you need to do bindings in your XAML, you do it like this:

```
<Button Content="{Binding LocalizedStrings.MainButtonText,
                          Source={StaticResource Resources}}" />
```

What you'll notice is that it doesn't work in Blend, **yet**. To make it work in Expression Blend,
add the following file: **DesignTimeResources.xaml** in the Properties Folder, and add following content

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace">
    <local:Resources x:Key="Resources" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now, you press F6 in Visual Studio to recompile, and voila, your localized strings are available in Expression Blend!

A real-world example from one of my projects:

- [AppResources.cs](https://bitbucket.org/Windcape/gocomics/src/0d1a718461c4/GoComics/Resources/AppResources.cs)
- [DesignTimeResources.xaml](https://bitbucket.org/Windcape/gocomics/src/0d1a718461c4/GoComics/Properties/DesignTimeResources.xaml)
- [App.xaml](https://bitbucket.org/Windcape/gocomics/src/0d1a718461c4/GoComics/App.xaml)